# MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock does not save object

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

This code works wonderful for me and Option is saved even when I rerun application.

```
 Player *selectedPlayer = [_players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

        Option *option = [Option MR_createInContext:localContext];

        option.playerID = selectedPlayer.playerID;

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"playerID == %@", selectedPlayer.playerID];

        Player *foundPlayer = [Player MR_findFirstWithPredicate:predicate inContext:localContext];

        [foundPlayer addOptionObject:option];

        [[STGameHelper sharedInstance].selectedGame addPlayersObject:selectedPlayer];

    } completion:^{

        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didSelectedPlayer)])
        {
            [self.delegate didSelectedPlayer];
        }

    }];
```

But if try this the data base does not have any Option objects after rerun application.

```
[MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

    Option *option = [Option MR_createInContext:localContext];

    option.playerID = selectedPlayer.playerID;

    Player *selectedPlayer = [_players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [selectedPlayer addOptionObject:option];

    [[STGameHelper sharedInstance].selectedGame addPlayersObject:selectedPlayer];

} completion:^{

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didSelectedPlayer)])
    {
        [self.delegate didSelectedPlayer];
    }

}];
```

I suppose that I work in different context, but I don't understand how it works under the hood. So the Player entries are stored in database without any issues. Why I can't choose already saved Player record and attach for this entity new record that has beed created in some context.

I suppose some context is distorted when I rerun app and the data base deletes Options entities using internal rules which selected for concert attribute (cascade etc). Am I right or maybe I confused?

Comment: On the surface, this looks less like a problem with MagicalRecord or CoreData, and more related to what the _players collection looks like. Is selectedPlayer nil in the second case? I'd say since you have a working solution, this also isn't a great question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really know nothing of MagicalRecord but ...
You do seem to have a cross context issue here ...

When using CoreData, a managed object is tightly bound to its managed context.
You cannot link objects from 2 different contexts.

In your second code segment you take an object inserted in `localContext` (which i believe is a temporary private queue context), your option, and link it to an existing object from another context (probably your main context).

You need to import the `selectedPlayer` to your local context by:

```
NSManagedObjectID* selectedPlayerID = [[_players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectID];
NSError* error = nil;
Player* selectedPlayer = [localContext existingObjectWithID:selectedPlayerID error:&error];
//handle error if needed ...
```

This will prevent your cross context issues.

Another thing:

Your code is executed in the background, so by the time it is executed `[_players objectAtIndex:...` might change.

You better obtain the player object id prior to declaring the block and trap that object ID in the block:

```
NSManagedObjectID* selectedPlayerID = [[_players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectID;
[MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^{/*your code here using selectedPlayerID*/}];
```